# What are the 3 recollection chants?

Tags: personal-practice, chant, chanting

What are the 3 recollection (protection) chants of the Buddha, the Dhamma and the Sangha?

It's told that they can be used to dispel fear.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Text and Chanting](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/lib/authors/dhammayut_khmer/eveningchanting_khmer#taṃ_kho..._a_guide_to_the_recollection_of_the_buddha) by Bhante Khemakumara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the chant with translation:

> Itipiso Bhagava (He is indeed the Exalted One)
>   Araham (far from
>   defilements)
>   Samma Sambuddho (perfectly enlightened by Himself)
>   Vijjacaranasampanno (fully possessed of wisdom and excellent conduct)
>   Sugato Lokavidu (knower of the worlds)
>   Anutaro Purisadhammasarathi
>   Sattha (unexcelled Trainer of tamable men)
>   Devamanussanam (teacher of
>   deities and men)
>   Buddho (the Awakened One)
>   Bhagavati (the Lord skilled
>   in teaching Dhamma)
>
> Svakkato Bhagavata Dhammo (well expounded is the Exalted One’s Dhamma)
>   Sanditthiko (to be seen here and now)
>   Akaliko (not delayed in time)
>   Ehipassiko ( (inviting one to) come and see)
>   Opanayiko (leading
>   inwards)
>   Paccatam Veditabbo Vinnuhiti (to be seen by each wise man for
>   himself)
>
> Supatipanno Bhagavato Savakasangho (that which is the Sangha of the
>   Exalted One’s disciple who have practiced well)
>   Ujupatipanno Bhagavato
>   Savakasangho (that which is the Sangha of the Exalted One’s disciple
>   who have practiced straightly)
>   Nayapatipanno Bhagavato Savakasangho
>   (that which is the Sangha of the Exalted One’s disciple who have
>   practiced rightly)
>   Samicipatipanno Bhagavato Savakasangho (that which
>   is the Sangha of the Exalted One’s disciple who have practiced
>   properly)
>   Yadittam (that is to say)  Cattari Purisayugani (the four
>   pairs of men- those who are in the four pairs of Noble Path and
>   Fruition)
>   Attha Purisapuggala (the eight types of individual persons-
>   those who are with the mind of a Stream Winner up to Fruition of
>   Arahantship)
>   Esa Bhagavato Savakasangho (that is the Sangha of the
>   Exalted One’s disciples)
>   Ahuneyyo (worthy of gifts)
>   Pahuneyyo (worthy
>   of hospitality)
>   Dakkkhineyyo (worthy of offerings)
>   Anjalikaraniyo (who
>   should be respected)
>   Anuttaram Punakkhetam Lokassati (incomparable
>   field of merit to the world)

(source http://methika.com/pali-chanting/itipiso-chant/)

Comment: Actually now that I look at the formatting of it, I think it is much easier to read at the source page btw.

Comment: Before the _Itipiso chant_, there are some [shorter chants](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yLdyW.jpg). Should i chant them first before going to the quoted ones?

Comment: This translation is full of extra little interpolations that exaggerate the words of the text. E.g. samma-sambuddho 'perfectly enlightened *by Himself*' where by himself is added. Bhagavati (the Lord skilled in teaching Dhamma) typo here bhagavā ti ("ti" is a separate word), it is usually translated "Blessed One". In the next line the same word is translated "Exalted One" which is a mistake. 

And so on. I also looks rather naked without the proper diacritics. There's a much better version here: http://www.oxfordbuddhavihara.org.uk/books/OBV%20Morning%20Chanting.pdf

Comment: Sādhu for pointing that out. I just picked the first convenient page off of google. I will update to a better translation asap.

Comment: @JayaravaAttwood. Thanks for sharing your knowledge about that.

Answer (score 3):

itipi so bhagavā
arahaṃ sammāsambuddho vijjācaraṇa-sampanno sugato lokavidū
anuttaro purisadamma-sārathi satthā deva-manussānaṃ buddho bhagavā ti

svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo,
sandiṭṭhiko akāliko ehipassiko opanayiko,
paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhī ti.

supaṭipanno bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho
uju-paṭipanno bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho
ñāya-paṭipanno bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho
sāmīci-paṭipanno bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho
yadidaṃ cattāri purisayugāni aṭṭha purisapuggalā
esa bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho
āhuṇeyyo pāhuṇeyyo dakkhiṇeyyo añjali-karaṇīyo
anuttaraṃ puññakkhettaṃ lokassā ti.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the interpolations.

This "works":

> Itipiso Bhagava (He is indeed the Exalted One)
>   Araham (far from defilements)
>   Samma Sambuddho (perfectly enlightened by Himself)

But accuracy and orthodoxy after 2750 years are important, my revered friends.
Buddha "*vachana*" brings serenity peace and above all progress.